# Request not processed asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have a service annotated with `@Async`. It is correctly processed in the threadExecutor, when called from another service, but not if called from a controller with requestmapping

```
@Service
public class StartupService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupService.class);
    @Autowired
    StockService stockService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if(event.getApplicationContext().getParent() == null) {
            LOGGER.debug("stockService.load call begin " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            stockService.reload();
            LOGGER.debug("stockService.load call end " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiController.class);
    @Autowired
    StockService stockService;

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/reload.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void reloadStock() {
        LOGGER.debug("stockService.load call begin " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        stockService.reload();
        LOGGER.debug("stockService.load call end " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

@Service
public class StockService {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StockService.class);

    @Async
    public void reload() {
        LOGGER.debug("stockService.load run begin " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //do the magic stuff
        LOGGER.debug("stockService.load run end " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Output is the following. When called from StartupService method in StockService is called in configured executor.
When called from ApiController method in StockService is called within the same thread

```
DEBUG [StartupService]: stockService.load call begin http-apr-8080-exec-70
DEBUG [StartupService]: stockService.load call end http-apr-8080-exec-70
DEBUG [StockService]: stockService.load run begin stockexecutor-1
DEBUG [StockService]: stockService.load run end stockexecutor-1

DEBUG [ApiController]: stockService.load call begin http-apr-8080-exec-85
DEBUG [StockService]: stockService.load run begin http-apr-8080-exec-85
DEBUG [StockService]: stockService.load run end http-apr-8080-exec-85
DEBUG [ApiController]: stockService.load call end http-apr-8080-exec-85
```

Comment: Are you using plain Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: how are you trigerring this crontroller method? vis browser? is the operation "do magic stuff" time consuming so as to see the difference

Comment: @M.Deinum: it is a spring applicaition

Comment: @pvpkiran the controller is triggered via browser. Do "the magic stuff" tasks about one minute, so i don't want anything to wait for it.

Comment: Then you have 2 instances of the service, one proxied for the async the other not. You probably have a `ContextLoaderListener` loading the same componetns as the `DispatcherServlet` effectivly duplicating bean instances.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are absolutely right. I used component-scan for the same package in spring-mvc-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml

Comment: The `ContextLoaderListener` should detect everything but web related beans (controllers, view resolvers etc.) and `DispatcherServlet` should only detect controllers, view resolvers etc. The other beans (services, repos, datasources) will be obtained from the parent application context. Doing this will also reduce the memory-footprint and prevent weird transactional and resource behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reposting the answer of @M.Deinum to mark this as the correct answer, because it helped me a lot.

> Then you have 2 instances of the service, one proxied for the async the other not. You probably have a `ContextLoaderListener` loading the same componetns as the `DispatcherServlet` effectivly duplicating bean instances

The problem was, that I used component-scan for the same package in spring-mvc-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml